# Altium Designer: How can you extract single members of a Harness?

Tags: schematics, altium

For better readability of the schematics I wanted to do something like in this image(Distributing the I2C-bus):[image: Example]

But I get "Conflicting Harness Definition for COM-IF" as a compile error.
Am I doing something wrong or is this impossible to achieve?

(The net label is because Altium sometimes requires one on a Harness for whatever reason to eliminate compile errors so I also tried it here, but no success)

Comment: I don't know Altium, but I do know other CADs. It looks like it thinks the open bracket is a definition of the entire harness. You may need to define the entire harness in one place, and then when you take individual signals from it you need to use a 'ripper' symbol, which pulls out a subset. Perhaps it thinks 'I2C' is a harness in its own right, and you can't sub-harness it into COM-IF, or can't do it like that. It's going to be something picky around the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it like this. If you have a harness connector it MUST always be completely the same in your schematic.

Yet, you could easily add a non-connected harness wire and name it COM_IF_NAME.I2C supposedly you give the harness wire the name COM_IF_NAME. Make it a habit to also give harness wires a net label and such a defined name.

Be aware that the harness type is different from the name. You can have multiple times the same harness connector type but connections will be made through the name.

E.g. you have a harness type UART which has 4 signals (RX, TX, RTS, CTS). You can name the harness wire UART1, UART2, UART3, ... and they will be seperate nets albeit sharing the same type.

In your schematic, you named your UART signals in a strange way. There is no need to add indices to them as the internal name will already be COM_IF_NAME.UART3.UART3_TX. Do yourself a favor and just name the harness entries TX and RX so the resulting name is COM_IF_NAME.UART3.TX.